# Customise ArrayAdapter to fill GridView from bottom-left

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I've got a GridView I'm using for a wordsearch app which I'm populating which a String Array. However I want to populate it from the bottom left going across and then up instead of the default top left going down.

I asked a question on here about it earlier and was told the way to achieve this is to write a custom ArrayAdapter which I have done, however I'm pretty new to Android and have no idea how to get the grid to fill from bottom left in the adapter.

I also still need to be able to get the element number of the item in the grid that is clicked, similar to what I'm doing now:

```
position = wordsearchGrid.pointToPosition((int)X, (int)Y);
```

This is the code I have so far for the custom adapter, it works, but still fills from top left obviously:

```
public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    Context context;
    Object[] items;
    int resource;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] items) 
    {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
            TextView cell;

            int cellWidth = 40;
            int cellHeight = 50;


            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                // If convertView is null then inflate the appropriate layout file
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            }

            cell = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridCell);

            cell.setText((CharSequence) items[position]);

            // Set height and width constraints for the image view
            cell.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight));

            // Set Padding for images
            cell.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

            return convertView;
    }
}
```

Could anyone give me a brief run-through on how I would go about getting the grid to fill so that the bottom left cell is the first element of the array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with customized ArrayAdapter. After checking GridView, I found that it is derived from AbsListView and there is [android:stackFromBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:stackFromBottom) attribute to specify stacking content from bottom or not.

```
<GridView ...
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
/>
```

By using android:stackFromBottom="false" element in GridView layout XML, I resolved the problem. FYI.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I discovered this after the hand in date haha, ended up writing a pretty annoying algorithm to switch the places of every entry.

Answer (score 0):

After spending most of the night on this I managed to figure out a way round it, not sure if this is the best way of doing it but it works exactly like I need it to.

```
public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
{
    Context context;
    Object[] items;
    int resource;
    int puzzleWidth;
    int newPosition;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    SparseIntArray positionMap = new SparseIntArray();

    public GridAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] items, int puzzleWidth) 
    {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
        this.puzzleWidth = puzzleWidth;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        //returns the new position
        return positionMap.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
            TextView cell;

            int cellWidth = 40;
            int cellHeight = 40;

            //works out the row number by rounding down position/puzzleWidth
            long rowNumber = (long)position / puzzleWidth;

            //changes position from top down to bottom up
            switch ((int)rowNumber)
            {
                case 0:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 1) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 3) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 5) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 7) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 9) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 11) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 13) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 15) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 17) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 19) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 21) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 23) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 25) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 27) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    newPosition = position + ((puzzleWidth - 29) * puzzleWidth);
                    break;
            }

            //store the old and new positions
            positionMap.put(position, newPosition);

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                // If convertView is null then inflate the appropriate layout file
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            }

            cell = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridCell);

            cell.setText((CharSequence) items[newPosition]);

            // Set height and width constraints for the textview
            cell.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight));

            // Set Padding for images
            cell.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

            return convertView;
    }
}
```